# Setting a default string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry guys, I think this is straight forward but I'm just not getting the result and have been trying/searching ages!

I'm looking to set a default caption (ie "There is no caption data") in a slideshow when no caption/title is present for a picture.  How can I do this?  The script is below, and thanks for taking look, and sorry for being a novice.

(This is in conjunction with PWI (Picasa Web integrator), jquery 1.8.3 and fancybox 2.1.4

A test page is also at http://www.talesfromthesaddle.com/photosTEST/photos.shtml

```
// This function is called by FancyBox to format the title of a picture
function formatPhotoTitleFancyBox() {
    var $title = this.element.title;
        this.title = $title;

    return;
    if (this.element.parentNode.childNodes && (this.element.parentNode.childNodes.length > 1)) {
        var $caption = $(".captiontext", this.element.parentNode);

        if ($caption.length > 0) {
            $title = $caption[0].innerHTML;
        }
        var $links = $(".downloadlink", this.element.parentNode);
        if ($links.length > 0) {
            var downloadLink = '<a style="color: #FFF;" href="' + $links[0].href + '">Download</a>';
            $title = $title + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + downloadLink;
        }
    }



title = $title;


}
```

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: At least you learned something new for all your life as programmer.

Comment: I had actually read that some days ago...but obviously forgot, let's hope I remember this time!

Comment: Funny that the world's most popular language is a trademark : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Trademark :)

Comment: I've found that the PWI title script is completely surplus.

I also notice that if I set 
    `fancybox_config: {
                config_photos: {
                    title: 'No caption data for this photo.',`

I can override the caption, but it overwrites all the captions....is there a means to stop it overwriting when a caption is present?

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like:

```
if ($caption.length > 0) {
    $title = $caption[0].innerHTML;
}
```

change to

```
$title = ($caption.length) ? $caption[0].innerHTML : "There is no caption data";
```

Comment: Hi Sudhir, like I've said in the above comment, I really appreciate the help.  I've tried this answer and also the one above, but for some reason the empty fields remain unpopulated, ie no default message.  I'll look more into it, perhaps there is some sort of conflict with the fancybox script....I don't know.  I'll keep trying, thanks again! Nick

Answer (score 0):

Fully embrace jquery -- right now you're doing it halfway.  Here is how I'd rewrite your function

```
// This function is called by FancyBox to format the title of a picture
function formatPhotoTitleFancyBox()
{
    var $elem = $(this.element);
    var title = $elem.attr('title') || 'No Caption'; // use || operator to set a default

    var caption = $elem.parent().find(".captiontext").html();
    title = caption || title; // if no html() found or no element found, default back to title

    var $links = $elem.parent().find(".downloadlink").first();
    if ($links.length > 0)
    {
        var downloadLink = '<a style="color: #FFF;" href="' + $links.attr('href') + '">Download</a>';
        title = title + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + downloadLink;
    }

    // finally, after ALL the edits to title, set this.title.  setting it above like in the OP question means all future changes are missed out on.

    this.title = title;

}
```

EDIT: Given the update in the comments on the OP, a suggestion I might make is: instead of using a function to set `this.title` instead make sure that all elements have an updated `title` attribute **BEFORE** you initialize your fancybox.  Something along the lines of:

```
$('.the-same-selector-for-fancybox').each(function()
{
    var $elem = $(this);
    var title = $elem.attr('title') || 'No Caption'; // use || operator to set a default

    var caption = $elem.parent().find(".captiontext").html();
    title = caption || title; // if no html() found or no element found, default back to title

    var $links = $elem.parent().find(".downloadlink").first();
    if ($links.length > 0)
    {
        var downloadLink = '<a style="color: #FFF;" href="' + $links.attr('href') + '">Download</a>';
        title = title + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + downloadLink;
    }

    // finally, after ALL the edits to title, set this.title.  setting it above like in the OP question means all future changes are missed out on.

    $(this).attr('title', title);
});

// call fancybox init here
```

By doing it like this, you're ensuring that each element has a title by the time fancybox initializes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look.  I've tried your script, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.  I had tried using the default || command myself, but the empty fields remain empty.  The existing captions continue to show up, but the default is not there.

At the moment at least this script is on the test page and can be seen at http://www.talesfromthesaddle.com/photosTEST/photos.shtml (The album "Peru Part 2, Andes" is full of uncaptioned images)

Perhaps there is some conflict between this script and fancybox?  I'll keep trying, thanks again it's nice of you to spend the time helping.

Comment: Your test case isn't very helpful.  I don't see my test method anywhere (I see a very different version with a different name of `formatPhotoTitleColorBox`).  And when I set a breakpoint there, the function isn't actually being called. Hard to debug when I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Sorry Eli, I'm trying (at least) a lot of things, maybe I should set up two test pages.  I'll reinstate it now, further apologies...

You should however, see my recent comment above (ie below my question/OP).

Comment: Thanks Eli, I'll look at this but as I had posted below I got the answer with just one line and an edit.  Seems to be working, and I've put it up on the live website....fingers crossed no bugs.  I really appreciate the time taken :)

Answer (score 0):

Right, apologies to all....looking further up the PWI script I found and appended a little as can be seen near the bottom, this seems to work....and seems the lower script is completely redundant?

```
function photo(j, hidden, username) {
            var $html, $d = "", $c = "", $youtubeId = "", $caption;
            if (j.summary) {
                var $matched = j.summary.$t.match(/\[youtube\s*:\s*(.*)\s*\](.*)/);
                if ($matched) { // Found youtube video entry
                    $youtubeId = $matched[1];
                    $c = $matched[2].replace(/[\r\n\t\s]+/g, ' ');
                    $caption = $matched[2].replace(/[\n]/g, '<br/>');
                } else {
                    $c = j.summary.$t.replace(/[\r\n\t\s]+/g, ' ');
                    $caption = j.summary.$t.replace(/[\n]/g, '<br/>');
                }
            }
            if (settings.showPhotoFilename) {
                if ($caption.length > 0) {
                    $caption += ", ";
                }
                $caption += settings.labels.fileName + " " + j.media$group.media$title.$t;
            }
            if (settings.showPhotoDate) {
                if ((j.exif$tags) && (j.exif$tags.exif$time)) {
                    $d = formatDateTime(j.exif$tags.exif$time.$t) + " ";
                }
            }
            var $pretitle = $c.replace(new RegExp("'", "g"), "&#39;");
            $title= $pretitle||'There is no caption'; //My appended line
            $d += $title;
```